# How do you set the signing identity from xbuild?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xbuild

I'm trying to get our jenkins set up and want the builds that come from it to be signed with a different identity than the Automatic Developer one. My current command looks like:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/xbuild Project.sln
/p:Target=Project.iOS  /p:Platform=iPhone /p:Configuration=Release
/p:BuildIpa=true /target:SigningKey="iPhone Distribution"  
/target:Build
```

this doesn't work. It is still trying to build with with developer cert. I can't seem to find any documentation on how do to this, any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `PropertyGroup` item you are trying to assign is:

```
<CodesignKey>iPhone Distribution</CodesignKey>
```

So depending upon what you are trying to build, something like this should get you started:

```
xbuild 
   /p:Configuration=Release 
   /p:Platform=iPhone 
   /p:BuildIpa=true
   /p:IncludeITunesArtwork=false 
   "/p:CodesignKey=iPhone Distribution"
   "/p:CodesignProvision=Automatic:AppStore"
```